# Poor workflow (UX) in job alerts - frustrating for users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The workflow for subscribing to a job alert on a company page, finding that job alert, deleting the job alert, and anything dealing with job alerts really needs work.

Go to a company page such as this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/148963/net-architect-meridian?so=i&sec=False&pg=1&offset=-1

There is a little section that reads **"Want to get notified about new jobs at Company X?"**:

[image]

Click this link to create the alert.  The UI should be interactive such that once you click this link, the "Create a company alert" should immediately change or at least a new link should appear next to it to "Manage" or "View" this alert.  But it doesn't, all you get is a confirmation that an alert was created.

Ok great...where the heck can I find my alerts.  I am an experienced user and I had a hard time finding job alerts tucked away behind this:

[image]

It would have been so much simpler had the user interface quickly allowed me to manage my newly created job alert considering I added it.  Telling me it added it with no link to it is misguiding the user.

So then after I had spent a long time finding my job alerts I am presented with this user interface, that makes it puzzling for me on how to delete a job alert I didn't even want - no confirmation when I clicked to add the job alert to test the UI:

[image]

I see two states on / off, but I don't see a remove option.  And it should be explicit...just because I turn it off doesn't mean I really even want it.  Please add a delete / remove option.  I don't want to unsubscribe if say I had 3 alerts using "Unsubscribe from all".

One thing that irks me about jobs in SO is I really do not believe the developers who work on it actually use it and if they do...do they run into the frustrations and the awkwardness that I run into?

**Feature request:**

I request that you guys try this out yourselves and see how some simple changes can make this a better system.  When you click to add a job alert, don't just throw up a message saying "yes added", actually make it such that a link appears as "manage this alert" or hide the "Create a company alert" since i just created the alert and make visible a new hyperlink allowing me to view this alert.

Second part is make getting to alerts easier, guide me.

Third part is allow me to manage alerts such that I can remove them.  Have a checkbox next to each alert and allow me to pick and choose which ones I want to remove.

Unsubscribe should work the same way such that I can click the checkbox for which alerts and click the "Unsubscribe" or "Delete" to take that action for any item that was checked.  Make the user interface as simple as an email interface - at the end of the day its a list of items and allow me to manage that list in a fast manner (using a checkbox grid).